# Converting PNG to GIF - Alpha channels are corrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, png, gif, javax.imageio

I have a PNG that I am converting to a GIF using objective-c (using the ImageIO framework), but my Alpha channels are being converted strangely.

For example, I have a red square with a glossy semi-transparent overlay ontop of the square to make it look like a bevel of some sort. I save the image as a PNG, and then in objective-c I try to convert it to a GIF. When it's converted the whole section where the semi-transparent gloss exists becomes solid white (or whatever color the UIView is behind the UIImage.)

I'm guessing I am not properly setting my dictionary values for my PNG image... so what are the possible values for:

kCGImagePropertyPNGInterlaceType

or

kCGImagePropertyPNGsRGBIntent

Here is my code for converting the gif to an animated gif and then copying it to the clipboard (which works, it just looses the alpha channel on some of my pngs)

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],
                                                                        kUTTypeGIF,
                                                                        16,
                                                                        NULL);


    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];
    //[dict setObject:(NSString *) ??? forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPNGInterlaceType];
    //[dict setObject:(NSString *) ??? forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPNGsRGBIntent];

    NSDictionary *frameProperties = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: dict
                                                                 forKey: (NSString*) kCGImagePropertyPNGDictionary ];




    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];

    const uint8_t colorTable2[ 9 ] = { 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 255,255,255};
    NSData* colorTableData2 = [ NSData dataWithBytes: colorTable2 length: 9 ];

    [dict2 setObject:colorTableData2 forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFImageColorMap];
    [dict2 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount];
    [dict2 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.005] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];

    NSDictionary *gifProperties = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: dict2
                                                                 forKey: (NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary ];



    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image1.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image2.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image3.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image4.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image5.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image6.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image7.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image8.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image9.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image10.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image11.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image12.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image13.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image14.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image15.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image16.image.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);

    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
    CFRelease(destination);

    NSData *gifData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    [pasteboard setData:gifData forPasteboardType:@"com.compuserve.gif"];

    [gifData release];
```

Comment: Note: It's becoming an animated gif.

Comment: GIFs do not have alpha.  They only have transparent colours.

Comment: What is a transparent color?

Comment: A colour index that is not drawn.  GIF is an indexed image format.  It has a palette of colours assigned to numbers.  You can make any of these a transparent colour, which means if a pixel uses that particular index, there will be no colour drawn - hence it is transparent.

Comment: As far as converting, I don't know about the library you're using, but you ought to be able to draw the PNG into an image that contains the background colour you want, and then pull that out as a GIF.  You might also need to mask the completely transparent areas.

Comment: How would you go about masking the transparent areas.